# Save description of a number of youtube videos

Tags: youtube

I need to save descriptions of a list of youtube videos. I want to feed the urls of videos (i.e. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sVtkQCz9Sx8) and then get the corresponding info of the "about" section of the youtube video. Is this possible for me to do without learning even basics of programming?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python 3, something like this :

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

with open('links.txt') as f:
    for link in f:
        page = urlopen(link)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())
        description_tag = soup.find(id='eow-description')
        upload_date_tag = soup.find(id='eow-date')
        print(link)
        print('Published on', upload_date_tag.text)
        print(description_tag.text)
        print()
```

Type your urls in links.txt (one url per lines).

Comment: Thanks moguchiy,
I know that python is a kind of programming language. Other than that I don't know how  your little script can help get the videos. Could you perhaps give more details on how to use it? Should I install the python software? Maybe save your script (where?) as an executable (what?) and launch it? That would help me as I've already hinted in the question, I've no knowledge and/or experience with programming ..

Comment: Sorry, you have to install [python 3](http://python.org/download) and [pip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) . Open a terminal and type `pip install beautifulsoup4` . Once done, simply save the script as for example "get_youtube_description.py" and in the same folder, create a file named "links.txt" and feed it with video urls. To run the script, open a new terminal, go to the directory where the script is and type `python get_youtube_description.py`

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it and post the results, if I have any, later.

Comment: It's quite incredible, but I managed to get the desired video infos with your script. Any idea if one can also get the upload date of the videos?

Comment: Fantastic. I think I learn how to output the whole data to a text file on my own. But perhaps you would do me one more favour - is it possible to save the comments to a video? That would be really great, as it would save me lots of time. Thanks for your expertise and help .. I'd never imagine such tasks could be accomplished so smoothly.

Comment: Everything is possible but it is harder to get the comments because they are dynamically loaded in JavaScript, I will try something later and post a new script if I get results.