# Youtube Video Description Scraper

Tags: facebook, video, youtube, web-scraping, web-crawler

I am currently using a Youtube scraper to get description from specific videos (music covers) and the descriptions have urls that I require (for instance, let say, facebook/username). Now the **scraper** pulls in the WHOLE description, however all I need is the Facebook link.

Would it be possible for someone to create such scraper? Possibly a "Scraper" where I feed it 10,000 Youtube video URLs and from those URLs it extracts the Facebook URLs and pastes them in a text document on each new line?

I found this topic here which is very similar to what I need doing, but I need JUST the Facebook URL. [Save description of a number of youtube videos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21856653/save-description-of-a-number-of-youtube-videos)

Comment: Got someone to program it.

Comment: care to share your results?

Comment: using iMacros I still need to feed the scrapper Youtube URLs however, once I start the macro, it extracts the relevant content I requested from the Youtube video page and saves it in plaintext. 

1) Goes to Youtube/watch/...
2) Extracts the URL parameter I want (facebook.com/.../)
3) Saves it in plain text on my machine
4) Rinse and Repeat until it goes through all Youtube urls in text doc

Comment: One, moment, I built something similar recently.  Take a look if this is relevant.

Answer (score -1):

```
class Namespace_Youtubecrawler_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{

    public function indexAction()
    {
        //this $hashes array, populated by youtube_videos_only_hash.txt, contains youtube identifiers.
        $hashes = array_unique(explode("\n", file_get_contents(Mage::getBaseDir('var') . DS . 'youtube_videos_only_hash.txt')));
        foreach ($hashes as $hash) {
            $json = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/' . $hash . '?v=2&alt=json'), true);
            $description = $json['entry']['media$group']['media$description']['$t'];
            //if page contains bit.ly or pagesize with the description then the video's URL is logged in custom log file.
            if ((strpos($description, 'pgsize') !== false) || (strpos($description, 'bit.ly') !== false)) {
                $outdatedURL = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' . $hash;
                Mage::log($outdatedURL, null, 'outdatedURLs.log', true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After I gathered a list of URLs for examination, using some quick excel functions, I chopped these URLs down to their constituent identifiers (that hash at the end of the youtube video url corresponds to it's 'location' on youtube).

I then used youtubes native JSON encoded pages (example):

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/oHg5SJYRHA0?v=2&alt=json&prettyprint=true

the above then examines the description for certain parameters.  I'm sure you can easily modify it to identify facebook URLs.  After finding the parameters it reassembles the youtube URL and logs it (on our server in this case).

Comment: That is whole lot different than mine. Id link you my code sample however its on my PC at home and can't VNC atm :(  (also deleted boot parameters this morning, eugh).

Anyway Il put that to the test, looks promising. I assume something like that would be adaptable to Soundcloud as well or any other website? I am in the process of making a scrapper of Facebook URLs for Soundcloud as well.

**+1**

Comment: @MisterK I used the json encoded youtube pages because it is much easier (and faster) to access an element in an array than to scan the entire page for an element and then examine the element itself to look at it's contents.  You can modify this to look at plaintext URLs easily.  Just look up how to examine elements and you're essentially off to the races.

Comment: wow that is fantastic, il crack on this tonight, thanks a ton! :)